# `justify-content` property not working on nested flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm quite new to HTML and CSS and I've encountered a problem with the menu I'm currently coding.

I'd like to make a menu using nesting flexbox. It's getting close to what I want but for a reason I cannot understand, the `justify-content` inside the children flexbox doesn't seem to apply...

Here is my code :

```css
header {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 90px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.avatar {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: inherit;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #00D717;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.avatar h1 {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}
.resteHeader {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: inherit;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
.resteHeader nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: inherit;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
.resteHeader nav ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: inherit;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="img/avatar.png">
    <h1>Hoang Nguyen</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="resteHeader">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="img/silhouette.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="img/bulle.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="img/cloche.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
    <form>
      Type sor search
      <input type="text">
      <img src="img/loupe.png" alt="">
    </form>
  </div>
</header>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Which container? What is the expected result?

Comment: `inline-flex` means make the container only as wide as it needs to be. It makes no sense to specify `justify-content: space-around` on an `inline-flex` container unless it also has a width (which a lot of your `inline-flex` containers do not)

Comment: don't use inline-felx just use display: flex;

Answer (score 6):

The `justify-content` property in your code is working fine.

The problem is you're using `display: inline-flex`, which makes the flex container only as wide as the content, leaving `justify-content` with no extra space to distribute.

Try using `display: flex` or adding `width: 100%` to your rules.

```css
header {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 90px;
    align-items: center;
    /* justify-content: flex-start;    OFF FOR TESTING */
    justify-content: flex-end;         /* WORKING */
    width: 100%;
}

.avatar {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: inherit;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #00D717;
    align-items: center; 
    /* justify-content: space-around;  OFF FOR TESTING */
    justify-content: flex-start;      /* WORKING */
}

.avatar h1 {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
}

.resteHeader {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: inherit;
    align-items: center;
    /* justify-content: flex-start;  OFF FOR TESTING */
    justify-content: space-between;  /* WORKING */
    width: 100%;
}

.resteHeader nav {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: inherit;
    align-items: center;
    /* justify-content: space-around;  OFF FOR TESTING */
    justify-content: center;           /* WORKING */
    width: 100%;
}

.resteHeader nav ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: inherit;
    align-items: center;
    /* justify-content: space-between; OFF FOR TESTING */
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="avatar">
        <img src="img/avatar.png">
        <h1>Hoang Nguyen</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="resteHeader">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/silhouette.png" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/bulle.png" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/cloche.png" alt=""></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="">

        <form>
            Type sor search
            <input type="text">
            <img src="img/loupe.png" alt="">
        </form>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! 
I've modified my code using flex instead of inline-flex and I've added "width : 100%;" to the header.

Comment: Working as intended now?

Comment: Not exactly... 
The resteHeader flexbox is not working properly : it should be extended through the whole page. Right now it's tucked in the left part, right after the avatar (which work juste fine).
(Sorry if my explanations are not easy to understand, english is not my native language).

Comment: The `resteHeader` *is* extending the whole page. I've wrapped a red border around it for illustration: https://jsfiddle.net/21oazr5z/

Answer (score 1):

`display:inline-flex` means make your container behave like an inline element - i.e. only as wide as it needs to be.

It makes no sense to specify `justify-content: space-around` on a `display:inline-flex` container unless the container also has a width (which a lot of your `display:inline-flex` containers do not)